How to set tmux style if command succeeds?
At work, I need to run a command to grant me access credentials for the day. The command needs to be run every 24 hours. If I spend the morning in meetings and get to the coding only in the afternoon, the credentials are valid until the next morning.
I display the status of the credentails in the status bar (e.g. output is Creds: 7h30m):
set-option -ga status-right 'Creds: #(credentials_remaining)'

The command does not show anything if there are no credentials (Creds: ) I typically do not notice the empty the status bar when the credentials expire.
Is there way to set the style of the status bar based on the command (e.g. has_credential --hours=<min remaining time>)? Ideally, I would like to change the color of credentials widget or even the whole status bar to bright red color to grab my attention. Hopefully something like
set-option -ga status-right '#{?has_credentials --hours=4,#[bg=#ff0000],#[bg=#44475a]}#(credentials_remaining)'

# or

set-option -g status-style '#{?has_credentials --hours=4,bg=#ff0000,bg=44475a},fg=f8f8f2

That does not seem to work.

The tmux server does not interpret has_credentials --hours=4 in your #{?has_credentials --hours=4,… as something it should run.
To run some shell code, you need #(). You have used this syntax in Creds: #(credentials_remaining).
Then keep in mind that #{?#(shell code here),first,second} runs shell code here in a shell, gets the output, strips all trailing newlines and gets the last line (if any). If after this the result is an empty string or 0 then the whole snippet will evaluate to what first evaluates to. If the result is anything else (including the kitchen sink, foo, whatever and 1, but also 00,     0, 0    ,   and such) then the whole snippet will evaluate to what second evaluates to.
This means that if has_credentials --hours=4 gives the answer in some way other than by outputting 0-or-nothing vs anything-else then you need to "translate" it to e.g. 0/1 printed to stdout. In particular, if it reports success by its exit status then the "translation" can be easily done with if.
In the following example we "translate" the exit status of test -e ~/foo which tests if ~/foo exists in the directory tree:
set-option -g status-style '#{?#(if test -e ~/foo; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi),fg=white#,bg=red,fg=red#,bg=white}'

Test the solution by alternately creating the file (touch ~/foo) and removing it (rm ~/foo). Note it may take several seconds until the tmux server re-runs the command and the style changes, so be patient.
Also note we needed to escape some , characters as #,. In the example first is fg=white#,bg=red and it evaluates to fg=white,bg=red when appropriate; second is fg=red#,bg=white and it evaluates to fg=red,bg=white when appropriate.
